# Как выбирать, какой фрагмент будет отображаться первым?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

пишу приложение с несколькими фрагментами(Расписание для ВУЗа), и работаю с ними через viewpager(для листания, соответсвенно), фрагменты хранятся в MainActivity, можно ли как-то управлять, какой фрагмент будет отображатся первым, точнее от какого фрагмента будет начинаться листание? Или это статитичное значение?Ну к примеру, в понедельник при открытии приложения сразу же отображается фрагмент с понедельником, во вторник будет отображтся фрагмент со вторником (если листнуть назад будет понедельник, вперед - среда)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);`
Используйте этот метод сразу после установки адаптера для ViewPager.
Например для установки первым фрагментом понедельник - `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет так, как написал автор выше. Если Вам любой способ подходит, а не именно через ViewPager, то можно сделать через заполнение фрагментом FrameLayout. Т.е., есть FrameLayout, вы создаете обьект фрагмента, и вставляете этот обьект в него. А по нажатию кнопок можно переключать эти фрагменты. А по поводу того, что конкретный фрагмент будет открыт на конкретный день, то можно получить текущую дату, и в зависимости от того, какой день, выводить конкретный фрагмент.